# How Vue3 pass dynamic segemet to nested router?

Tags: vue.js

Coding Enviroment: Vue3, JavaScript

Router code:

```
  {
    path: '/group/:id',
    component: Group,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'homework_list',
        component: HomeworkList,
      },
      {
        path: 'member_list',
        component: GroupMemberList
      },
    ]
  },
```

Vue code:

```
<router-link to="homework_list">Homework List</router-link>
```

First I can visit the link http://localhost:3333/group/1, when I click the `router-link`, I want to go a URL like **http://localhost:3333/group/1/homework_list**, but it just go to the URL http://localhost:3333/group/homework_list.

I know I can change the **router-link** like following code to implement the function. But the `id` is not static.Is it necessary to add the `id` value of current link to all `route-link`? It seems a bit troublesome.

```
<router-link to="1/homework_list">Homework List</router-link>
```

My English is not so good, if there is any inappropriate expression, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

`to` property of router-link is just like any other property of your custom components and as such, it can be dynamic. For example, let's assume that you have `groupId` property in your data

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="groupId + '/homework_list'">Homework list</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      groupId: 15
    }
  }
</script>
```

Note that there is a big difference between `to="foo"`, and `:to="foo"`. The first one is static (string `foo`) and second one is dynamic (referencing property named `foo`) - meaning that every time that property changes it will be propagated to the child components.

You can read about it further [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)